# User Folder VBA Reference Location (for xlwings)

Tags: python, excel, vba, windows, xlwings

I have a macro-enabled spreadsheet that uses xlwings' `RunPython` function.

```
Sub button()
    RunPython ("from blah.blah.file import fuction; function()")
End Sub
```

If I go to `Tools->References` in Excel VBA I can enable xlwings reference and run this button but the reference is installed in the location:

```
C:\Users\[MY_USERNAME]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART
```

so if I give the sheet to my coworker who has a different user name (instead of `MY_USERNAME`) Excel can't find the xlwings reference even if they have xlwings installed.

Is there a way to generically reference the User folder? or maybe just a better way to install the xlwings reference?

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to find the username that is used for that path you can use `(Environ$("Username"))`

So your path would be 
`"C:\Users\" & (Environ$("Username")) & "\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART"`

If you are wanting to add References from Tools -> Reference programmatically here is the pseudocode.

`1. Loop through your Reference objects to see if it currently exists in your project. 
 2. If not, add the Reference by Name, GUID, or Path.`

I prefer using GUID because it doesn't change with different computers.

This wouldn't solve the issue if the library/reference isn't already installed on their computer. Trying to have the Excel file install a library/reference would be a much larger project.

If you need further help please let me know, but give it shot trying to program it first and then we can help walk you through it.

Comment: Just a side note: `"C:\Users\" & (Environ$("Username"))` -> `Environ$("Userprofile")`

Comment: Thank you BigBen.. Learning something new everyday from you!

Comment: Just passing the knowledge along - someone did the exact same to me before :-)

Comment: I even found the original comment! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49762782/vba-save-as-pdf-into-a-shared-folder-with-different-computer/49762955#comment86544457_49762955

Comment: This seems like what I'm looking for, but I'm not sure how to implement it.  If I go to "Tools -> References" in Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications (in Excel) I have to browse for the file rather than entering a path of strings.

Comment: Maybe to be more clear adding a reference is not inside VBA code, but seemingly a property of the Excel file.

Comment: Crap.  OK.  The hope was I wouldn't have to use VBA code to load the reference in the same way I wouldn't have to use code to load the Bloomberg API or Microsoft Excel Object Library.  I could just click Tool -> Reference like I would do with those.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way to ensure that the library/reference is added with the file so that everyone who has the file also has the library/reference without using programming.